# Is there a google sheets formula that matches two tables to find approximate matches?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to see how you can match two data sets, but only return the matched value.
[see image of an example data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfHlb.png)

I want the formula to read List 1 and compare to List 2 and be able to denote that row 2,3,5,6 and 8 contains values that are similar to what is in List 2

I used the following formula, but the match rate was low

`arrayformula(if(isblank(G7:G50000)=TRUE,"", vlookup("*"&G7:G50000&"*",Dropdowns!K:K,1,false)))`

Tried this formula, but Aggregate formula does not work in Google Sheets:

`IFERROR(INDEX(Dropdowns!K:K,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Dropdowns!$K$2:$K$500)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Dropdowns!$K$2:$K$500,G8))),1)),"")`

Tried the following formula, but "contains" needs to be specific and it doesn't allow me to search from a table.

`=query(K:K,"Select K where K contains 'Lead'")`

Comment: Can you post a "from this -> to this" example that you want to achieve?

Comment: What kind of contents is it? numbers or strings? . Please show some data and your desired result.

Comment: Its strings. I have edited the question to include more info

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "similarity" is very complex and can be understood in many ways.

What you show in your example is checking whether a string in table 2 is included in table 1.

You can test it using regexextract:

```
=arrayformula(ifna(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B7,join("|",F3:F4))))
```

[image]

This formula lets you build longer tables and only limit is 50 000 characters for table 2 (together with | separator).